# Sub-domains treated as external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a class `external` to all the external hyperlink URLS. To achieve this I wrote the javascript

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(a => {
    a.classList.add(location.hostname === a.hostname || !a.hostname.length ? 'internal' : 'external');
});
```

The issue is that the sub-domains are also treated as external and the respective `<a>` tag is getting `external` class added. How can I exclude the hyperlinks of sub-domains and also 2 other domains (abc.com and xyz.com) from having the `external` class added?

Comment: @James: see [`HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `location.hostname === a.hostname` I would try `location.hostname.idexOf(a.hostname) >= 0`